# redirection bash: content from variable, not from file

Tags: bash, redirect, mutt

i am using mutt to create and send mails from a bash script.

like this:

> $ mutt -s SUBJECT MAIL_TO_ADDRESS  < BODY_CONTENT_FILE

So i always have to write a file before calling mutt, is there a solution to pass information directly from script or shell variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

For literal content, you can use a here-document:

```
mutt -s "$SUBJECT" "$ADDRESS" <<EOF
body of message goes here
and all of it is included
until you have a line with the terminator
which is whatever you put after the `<<`
in this case,
EOF
```

Note that parameters will be expanded inside the here-document as if it were a double-quoted string, unless you quote the terminator (with e.g. `<<"EOF"`), in which case it will be treated as a a single-quoted string instead.

If it's a short message, or already in a variable, it's probably easier to use a here-string instead:

```
mutt -s "$SUBJECT" "$ADDRESS" <<<"$BODY"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a here document

```
$ mutt -s SUBJECT ADDRESS <<EOF
long
multiline
message
EOF
```

or, if the message is short, `bash` allows a here string:

```
$ mutt -s SUBJECT ADDRESS <<< "short message"
```

Either can contain a parameter expansion if you already have the text in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

The expression `< BODY_CONTENT_FILE` at the end of a line is the same as `cat BODY_CONTENT_FILE |` at the beginning of the line.

So you can use the following snippet if your content is in a variable:

```
echo $VARIABLE | mutt -s SUBJECT MAIL_TO_ADDRESS
```

You can replace `echo $VARIABLE` by whatever you want which its output is on stdout.

Comment: so redirection from file is the same as piping in general ?

Comment: @user3336433, not *quite* the same thing -- redirection from a file gives you a direct FD connected to the file, meaning it's more efficient and you can `seek()` in it, whereas piping from `cat` gives you a pipeline end connected to a `cat` process that's responsible for reading; being a pipe, it doesn't allow jumping around in the stream -- you can read from it or close it, but can't, say, rewind. Still, they both control what stdin is connected to, and both piping from `cat file` and redirecting with `<file` will put the contents of `file` on the other end of stdin (FD 0).